# BasicFilter AuthHelper.containsAuthenticationData(httpRequest) returns false

Tags: java, azure, adal

I am trying to check the sample Java Azure AD project provided by Microsoft and I am getting an error when trying to authenticate.

I created my app, so I have my client_id, whose Sign-On URL is

```
http://localhost:8080, (instead of http://localhost:8080/adal4jsample).
```

Then, I configured my tennant name and client id in the web.xml, and once I launch the web app I can "log in" but, when I come back to my domain I see the error.jsp page.

After debugging, I can see that

```
AuthHelper.containsAuthenticationData(httpRequest)
```

is giving false because the request parameter map does not contain the ID_TOKEN or CODE. Actually, it is empty.

But, if I inspect the http calls in my browser I am able to see, this

```
Request url: http://localhost:8080/secure/aad
Form data:
    code:${code}
    id_token:${id_token}
    session_state:${session_state}
```

So, in the filter the request does not have the parameters, but when calling to the secure/add controller I do have them. But, since I did not create the principal parameter, I get the error.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, it was due to the azure app did not have a key set.